# Using AWS S3 Bucket as a NoSql Solution

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3, nosql

We have an application that makes an API request and then stores the xml response in an RDS MySql Database.

These xml responses are huge, and are taking up too much RDS storage.
I understand it's possible to store these instead in an S3 Bucket, since it is a key/value store much like DynamoDb.

Does anyone have any experience doing this in PHP?

The requirements would be that our application should have no issue writing 1000s of S3 entries per minute. We would also need to be able to retrieve an entry from S3 in realtime, just like we would if we were doing a mysql query for the xml response (which we currently do now).

Answer (score 0):

RDS is for relational data where you want to be able to query using complex SQL queries (Joins, Filters etc.)

S3 is for static(ish) file storage & serving, without filtering. You get back the whole file (not part of it) at a time.

You can probably shoehorn both of them into doing what you want, but you'd be best off choosing the one that fits the type of read/write/access type that you require.

If you want to serve files like you describe in your question you're probably best off with S3. You can use their [official SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html) to handle the downloads and uploads.